# Размещение всех слоев на экране - HTML / CSS / bootstrap

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

Подскажите, можно ли средствами HTML, CSS и bootstrap разместить все слои на экран, но так чтобы они в дальнейшем были также еще и адаптивны? Если можно так сделать, то как?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все можно сделать. Покажите, что у вас уже готово.